# Is there any way / tool to test intermittent internet connectivity problems?

Tags: internet, connection

Is there a tool to test intermittent internet connectivity problems? I believe I am having some at work but I can't prove it without solid evidence. Tracert isn't that great of an option as the internet connection is usually pretty good except for a second here and there, but that second causes big issues.

Answer (score 4):

I deal with this sort of troubleshooting on a daily basis. The hard part about intermittent issues is determining where it is intermittent - you need the where before you can determine the why. The best way to start is to remove as many variables as possible. The best method is to start with your ISP device (t1 router, dsl modem, cable modem, etc) and connect it right up to the DMARC (smart jack if it is a t1, bonding device if it is eoc) using a new, short patch cable. Connect a laptop to the ISP device and run ping tests to your ISP's primary DNS (this is typically at your first hop and the best place to start). It it is only for a few seconds, set your ping intervals to 200 ms instead of 1 second and let it run overnight. If you see problems here, then it is your ISP's issue and you need to call them, they will do the rest.

Now if you see no issues here, then your problem is your IW or something on your network. Connect the ISP device back up to where you had it before and again, connect with just a laptop and run the same ping test again. If this is clear, then your IW is fine, and you know it is your network, if it is not clear, then run new cabling between there and the DMARC.

Troubleshooting your network is not something I'd be able to help with unless I had more information about it's setup, but the basics are to test the same way at each joint (typically routing point or switch) to see when the problem starts occurring again. This is not always easy, or successful, so sometimes tcpdump is required to watch traffic and see what is happening. This is not always easy and can be very time consuming, but may be your best bet.

Comment: A quick google suggests that DMARC is the demarcation point between you and the ISP, but what does IW stand for out of curiosity?

Comment: @Thick_propheT, correct, DMARC (also called a NID) is the box on the side of your house/building that has the demarcation point between the wires coming in from the street and the IW (inside wiring). It is the point at which responsibility for the wiring moves from the telco to the property owner.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.measurementlab.net/run-ndt
Someone who knows the theories could probably get enough information about the detailed information this tool gives you.